# JavaScript 2 dimension array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have 3 arrays

```
var city = [
  ['Kaunas', 54.896872,23.892426],
  ['Vilnius', 54.711136,25.280685],
  ['Klaipeda', 55.720149,21.131401],
  ['Utena', 55.536403,25.59494],
];

var lake = [
  ['Ezeras Bijote', 55.785092,23.062956],
  ['Ezeras Druksiai', 55.627996,26.565228],
  ['Ezeras Sartai', 55.804368,25.832863],
  ['Ezeras Metelys', 54.300299,23.767004],
];

var shop = [
  ['Kauno Akropolis', 54.891665,23.917744],
  ['Panorama', 54.709549,25.257454],
  ['Europa', 54.687514,25.262886],
  ['Ozas', 54.638628,25.135685],
];
```

I want add this 3 arrays to 1 array ut don't know how to do this, will very nice if i can call form alements like this `bigArr[city][1]`, `bigArr[shop][1]`,`bigArr[lake][1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what you already have:

`var bigArr = {"city": city, "lake": lake, "shop": shop};`

Comment: `bigArr["city"][0]` is the same as `city[0]`

Comment: You can also use `bigArr.city[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [compact()](http://phpjs.org/functions/compact:371).

Alternatively, just declare it as an object already:

```
var myObject = {
    city: [
        ....
    ],
    lake: [
        ....
    ],
    shop: [
        ....
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create an object instead of a multidimensional array -

```
var bigArr = {
    "city": {
        Kaunas: {
            "lat": 54.896872,
            "lon": 23.892426 
        },
        Vilnius: {
            "lat": 54.711136,
            "lon": 25.280685
        },
        Klaipeda: {
            "lat": 55.720149,
            "lon": 21.131401
        },
        Utena: {
            "lat": 55.536403,
            "lon": 25.59494
        }
    },

    "lake": {
        ...
    },

    "shop": {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then you can use it, like `bigArr.city.Kaunas.lat`

Comment: Never store numbers as strings!

Answer (score 1):

You should use Objects instead of Arrays. You can access them by string keys. Create them as a literal:

```
var coordinates = {
    "city": {
        Kaunas:   [54.896872,23.892426],
        Vilnius:  [54.711136,25.280685],
        Klaipeda: [55.720149,21.131401],
        Utena:    [55.536403,25.59494]
    },
    "lake": {
        ...
    },
    "shop": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then access their properties by using [member operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators):

- Dot notation: `coordinates.shop`
- Bracket notation: `coordinates["lake"]`

To get the coordinates array for Utena, you might use `coordinates.city["Utena"]`